# Having trouble using setState on an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I'm having trouble using setState on an empty array. I have an empty array in my state, and I'm trying to populate it from another function using setState.

`dataProcessing.js`:

```
const calculate = () => {
    let series = [{
        name: "Sports",
        data: [
            {
                name: "Baseball",
                y: 13
            },
            {
                name: "Football",
                y: 20
            }
    }]

    return series;
  }
  export default calculate;
```

`Main.js`:

```
import calculate from './dataProcessing';

export default class Main extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      series: []
    };
  }

  calc = () => {
    this.setState = ({
      series: [... calculate()]
    })
   }  
}
```

After the `calc()` function gets executed, `this.state.series` is still an empty array. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you checking `this.state.series`?

Comment: I was calling it in the render()

Answer (score 1):

You want a method bound to `this`, and to call this.setState, not to set this.setState =

```
  calc() {
    this.setState({
      series: [... calculate()]
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is async. Once you call setState your component will re-render

You can use the callback of setState to get the new updated state.

```
this.setState = ({
   series: [...calculate()];
}, (newState) => {
   console.log(newState);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

dataProcessing.js:

```
const calculate = () => {
    let series = [{
        name: "Sports",
        data: [
            {
                name: "Baseball",
                y: 13
            },
            {
                name: "Football",
                y: 20
            }
        ]
    }]
    return series;
}
export default calculate;
```

Main.js:

```
import calculate from './dataProcessing';

export default class Main extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            series: []
        };
    }

    calc = () => {
        this.setState = ({
            series: [...calculate()]
        }, () => {
            console.log("series", this.state.series)
        })
    }
}
```